# Ruby on Rails - unable to open mySQL command line

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, command-line

I am able to open the mySQL command line doing the following steps:

```
depot>mysql -u root
mysql>CREATE DATABASE depot_production DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON depot_production.* TO 'gotqn' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
mysql>EXIT;
```

then changing my *config/database.yml*

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: depot_production
  pool: 5
  username: gotqn
  password: mypass
  host: localhost
```

and final typing:

> gotqn:~/Aptana Projects/depot$mysql depot_production

gives me:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'gotqn'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

I've supposed that I should specified a password but typing:

> gotqn:~/Aptana Projects/depot$mysql depot_production mypass

just shows me the some variables information.

I am using:

1. Rails 3.2.8
2. mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using
   readline 6.2
3. Ubuntu LTS 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Configuration file *config/database.yml* is for Ruby, not for mysql command line tool. For command line tool use correct syntax:

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
```

by default it uses your current logged in user if --user=user_name is omited.

Answer (score 0):

In database.yml use username as root:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: depot_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the user in mysql as `@'localhost'`

```
    mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON depot_production.* TO 'gotqn'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```